# How to delete a node in an elasticsearch cluster without making it crash?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and I have to remove documents from a remote node in a cluster without making it crash. How do I add an endpoint node in the cluster. I am not able to find anything that could help me guide toward it.

Comment: Why do you need to remove documents from that node?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To add updated documents in the node. I haven't been able to find solution for uploading data